# How can I find repeated dates in this VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba

How can I find repeated dates in the array DataInicio in this code? I need to find ALL repeated dates and how many times. It is not useful for me to know it is just repeated.

Thanks!

I have been trying to figure out but nothing is working.

```
Sub EscalaDinâmicaHTA()

Dim NumHelis As Integer
Dim DataInicio(1 To 15) As Date
Dim DataFim As Date
Dim ContData As Double
Dim LinHeliInicial As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

a = 1

Do While LinHeliInicial <= LinTotal

i = 2
j = 3
k = 4

Do While i <= 14 And j <= 15 And k <= 16      '26,27,28

DataInicio(a) = Worksheets(1).Cells(LinHeliInicial, i).Value
ContData = DateValue(DataInicio(a))
ContData = Val(ContData)

DataFim = Worksheets(1).Cells(LinHeliInicial, j).Value
DataFim = DateValue(DataFim)

Duracao = DataFim - DateValue(DataInicio(a))
Worksheets(1).Cells(LinHeliInicial, k).Value = Duracao + 1
Duracao = ContData + Duracao
Duracao = Val(Duracao)

ContData = ContData - 43072         '43072 é a descontar as colunas A,B,C,D,etc até ao começo do calendário
Duracao = Duracao - 43072


Do While ContData <= Duracao
Cells(LinHeliInicial, ContData).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
ContData = ContData + 1
Loop

k = k + 3
j = j + 3
i = i + 3

a = a + 1

Loop

LinHeliInicial = LinHeliInicial + 1

Loop


End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show us how do you have stored your data in your Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This outputs number of duplicates in an array. Note that it will output the same element multiple times, if it occurs multiple times. This can be easily fixed by keeping track of checked elements in another array, and only check them if not checked before (i.e. making an array with unique entries for checking).

```
Dim counter As Integer
Dim varElement1 As Variant
Dim varElement2 As Variant

'get element within array
For Each varElement1 In array
    'reset counter
    counter = 0
    For Each varElement2 In array
        'compare varElement1 with each element of array
        If varElement2 = varElement1 Then
            'increase counter if match was found (1 will alway be found -> the element itself)
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
    Next varElement2
    'output number if more than 1 (more than itself) was found
    If counter > 1 Then
        Debug.Print varElement1 & " occured " & counter " times"
    End If
Next varElement1
```

Edit: simplified code, added comments

Comment: how should i implement it? I put it after the last loop and changed array to DataInicio but it does nothing.

Comment: Did you check the [immediate window](https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/vba-immediate-window-excel/) for output? Did you instantiate (dim) all the variables?

Comment: Yes... I have now runtime error 1004 since I quited the "on error resume next"

Comment: It doesn't returns the number of repetitions correctly.